# How to start page loading animation and stop on page loaded

Tags: android

I am developing one Android application which is connecting to Web Service. How can I keep page loading animation while redirecting to another page ? I have tried following code but whenever I have pressed back button the loading animation is remains on previous page. And sometimes blank screen is coming. Please help me to improve my code and help me to resolve this issue.

```
public void redirection()
    {   
        ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "","Please wait...", true);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondClass.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Comment: Dismiss the dialog before moving to the secondclass using   dialog .dismiss();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow that link http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/

Here define the animations

method start

```
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
}
```

method end

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use asytask in this process...

```
public class asynclass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "","Please wait...", true);
    }

@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

//do your work which u want 
}
}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        dialog .dismissDialog();

//and here u can pass intent if u want to pass 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope that you are using AsyncTask for to download your data ..

Initiate progress dialog as

```
Private ProgressDialog pDialog;
```

Try putting this code on onPreExecute()..

```
@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getParent());
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
```

And on PostExcute stop progress dialog after you completly downloaded data as

```
pDialog.dismiss();
```